# Escaping period character when enumerating JSON object

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to extract some information using Azure Data Explorer from the Qualys vulnerability scanner logs.

I have got the below KQL, and it all works fine except for line 9. I'm trying to extract information from the returned json object, but the key name has a period in it i.e. **2.0** and I can't work out how to escape it so that I can still use the JSON dot notation.

```
securityresources | where type =~ "microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments"
        | extend assessmentKey=extract(@"(?i)providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/([^/]*)", 1, id), QID=tostring(properties.id), parentResourceId= extract("(.+)/providers/Microsoft.Security", 1, id)
        | extend resourceId = tostring(properties.resourceDetails.id)
        | where properties.additionalData.assessedResourceType =~ "ServerVulnerability" or properties.additionalData.assessedResourceType =~ "GeneralVulnerability"
        | where  properties.additionalData.source =~ "Built-in Qualys vulnerability assessment"
        | extend vulnerabilityName=tostring(properties.displayName),
                vulnerabilityType = tostring(properties.additionalData.assessedResourceType),
                virtualMachineName=split(properties.resourceDetails.id, "/")[-1],
                cvss2Score = tostring(properties.additionalData.cvss.\(2.0).base)
        | project QID, vulnerabilityName, virtualMachineName, vulnerabilityType, cvss2Score
```

JSON structure:

```
{
    "2.0": {
        "base": 7.6
    },
    "3.0": {
        "base": 7.5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see: [Dynamic object accessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic#dynamic-object-accessors).

for example:

```
print properties = dynamic({
    "additionalData":{
        "cvss":{
            "2.0": {
                "base": 7.6
            },
            "3.0": {
                "base": 7.5
            }
        }
    }
})
| project base = todouble(properties.additionalData.cvss['2.0'].base)
```

| base |
| --- |
| 7.6 |